# #include virtual in .html file

Tags: cgi, ssi

I'm moving over a site that is built on CGI. I have all the .cgi pages working properly, but a couple .html files contain `<!--#include virtual="show_testimonials.cgi" -->` but won't output the script within the html file.

Do I need to add something specifically to my .htaccess file to get Server Side Includes to work?

Answer (score 2):

try to rename to `.shtml` or check your apache config. There you can also specify the SSI handler to parse `.html` files.

Answer (score 0):

```
AddHandler server-parsed html
```

in your .htaccess file will cause *all* your .html files to be parsed by the server.